# Manage external files when set Shadow build in Qt (Win8)

Tags: qt

My problem is to manage some text tables contained in a folder used in my Qt project; when I compile release or debug version, I must copy the same folder in all place where project is compiled. The disadvantage is when I change a data in one of text tables and forget to copy this table in all places.
Is it possible to set an absolute path or an unique folder for all files in some ways external to Qt sources, headers and classes file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QMAKE_POST_LINK to add a custom copy command after your build process is finished.

For example I use this code in my PRO file to copy the release executable into a dedicated bin folder that is used for building a setup executable.

```
win32 {
    release {
        COPY_CMD = "$$OUT_PWD\\release\\$${TARGET}.exe $$PWD\\bin\\$${TARGET}.exe"
        COPY_CMD = $${QMAKE_COPY} $$replace( COPY_CMD, "/", "\\" ) $$escape_expand( \\n\\t )
        QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$COPY_CMD
    }
}
```

You can do the same, just in the other direction and copy your needed files into your build path.

For example, this would create a folder MyList in your build path and copy every *.txt from your source root to this folder.

```
win32 {
    release {
        COPY_CMD += mkdir $$OUT_PWD/MyList &
        COPY_CMD += copy $$IN_PWD/MyList/*.txt $$OUT_PWD/MyList/*.txt &
        COPY_CMD = $$replace( COPY_CMD, "/", "\\" ) $$escape_expand( \\n\\t )
        QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$COPY_CMD
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a bit complicated for my poor experience.
I tried using DESTDIR put in PRO file to move executable file into source and header files folder (the same in which there's the folder containing my text tables). It seems to work...maybe a good solution for my aim.

Comment: You shouldn't copy executables to your source/header folders, I meant to copy your text file to your shadow build path.
Try this:

    COPY_CMD += copy $$IN_PWD/yourtextfile.txt $$OUT_PWD/release/yourtextfile.txt &

Comment: You're right; but files I've to copy are more than fifty and this list can increase, forcing me to edit the PRO file every time I add a text file.

Comment: If you have that many files it is natural to have them in an extra resource folder, you can then copy the complete folder and don't need to worry about new files in that folder.

Comment: Sure, but not clear how: e.g. suppose my folder is "MyProgram/MyList" and when I compile in Release mode, executable file is "Build_MyProgram_Release", which is the command to put in my PRO file?

Comment: I have added an example with MyList to my original answer. This is the exact same code I use in a different project, so this should work I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88490/discussion-between-beowolve-and-littlesaints).